# What tools exist for manipulating HTML in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation

I have a Node.js/Express application which takes user input as HTML, and I need to make it both well-formed and remove or replace all but a small subset of allowed tags. What are the existing options for doing so?

For example, after cleaning, I might want to regard `<div><br></div>` as empty and remove it, and replace `<div>Text</div>` with `<p>Text</p>`.

**EDIT**

@kaareal suggests htmltidy, which deals nicely with the cleaning it up part. How can I take this clean output and remove or replace elements?

Answer (score 2):

I only know of one library "htmltidy"

There is already a wrapper for it
https://npmjs.org/package/htmltidy

Comment: Looks good, but as far as I can see there's no way of removing or replacing arbitrary tags? For example, much of my input has <div> where I want <p>.